# Sort objects by their string field including language specific characters

Tags: java, collections

I would like to sort list of my objects by their string name field. But those names have some polish characters and because of that sorting is not correct. I've made some research about the issue and found out that I should use something like:

```
Collections.sort(myList, Collator.getInstance());
```

But the problem is that it works only when I would try to sort list of strings. When i try to sort list of my objects i get `java.lang.ClassCastException`.
How can I sort list of my objects in alphabetical order in polish language?

My object looks something like this:

```
public class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject>{
     private String name;
     ...

     @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull MyObject object) {
        return name.compareTo(object.getName());
    }
```

And right now I try to sort it like this:

```
List<MyObject> myList = DataProvider.getInstance().getListOfObjects();    
Collections.sort(myList, Collator.getInstance());
```

Comment: Can `name` hold also non-Polish characters like German, French? If yes how would you like to order those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there's some ambiguity in the `Collator` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html).

`Collator` is a `Comparator<Object>`, but it really is aimed at performing

> locale-sensitive **String** comparison
>   (emphasis mine).

You can see this better in the `Collator#compare` concrete implementation's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#compare(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)):

> This implementation merely returns compare`((String)o1, (String)o2)`.

---

The `ClassCastException` you're getting is likely due to the fact that obviously `MyObject` is not `String`.

---

I would try moving the usage of `Collator` in your actual `compareTo` implementation:

```
Collections.sort(myList);
```

... and in your `compareTo` implementation:

```
Collator.getInstance().compare(name, object.getName());
```

---

Note that the `Collator.getInstance()` idiom uses the default `Locale`.

Therefore, if you plan on using multiple `Locale`s to compare your objects depending on context, you may be better off sorting with a custom `Comparator` that allows injecting a `Locale` and using `Collator` under the hood.

Comment: I've implementing the sorting the way you proposed, using collator inside compareTo implementation. And now I get error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!`

Comment: @matip did not occur within my replication (with your exposed conditions), however I did not annotate the parameter as `@NonNull`. If you haven't added extra code compared to your question, try getting rid of that, as it may violate the signature of the override for all I know. You should in fact handle `null` cases within the `compareTo` body.

Comment: Well accualy I am handling null cases inside compareTo body. Only when names are not null I use `Collator.getInstance().compare`

Comment: @matip there's probably something wrong with your implementation, but it's hard to guess without the actual code.

Comment: I managed to make it work. When I was handling null case in compareTo method I was returning 0. Now I am returnig 1 in such cases and everything works

Comment: @matip that explains it yes. `0` would imply the objects are to be considered equal, which would not make sense if one of them is `null` and the one executing `compareTo` obviously isn't :)

Answer (score 1):

`Collator` is used to compare strings, you can extract the name then pass them to `Collator`:

```
myList.sort((o1, o2) -> Collator.getInstance().compare(o1.getName(), o2.getName()));
```